# VAE latent vector not taking unit normal distribution

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes

I trained a Convolutional VAE on 1-D electric load curve data (one sample consists of 48-time steps). The training loss (mean square error + KL divergence) decreases during training and is converging. I am able to get satisfactory reconstruction on both training and test data.  I didn't normalize my input data since it was already within the range 0 to 1.

The problem is that my latent vector (z) is taking on very large values for a given input vector. From what I understand of VAE's isn't z supposed to take on a zero mean, unity variance normal distribution after training. Otherwise, how can we sample z for generating new data? Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the reason z was taking large values was due to a bug in my code. I had forgotten to return the regularization term in the KL divergence loss function. Once I added that I found that z was taking values similar to a normal distribution after training.